# JSPlumb diagram to JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, jsplumb

I've been developing a diagramming tool, I used JSPlumb.

I made shapes using css and connections are made through JSplumb.

I need to save the diagram as json or xml format. But I am having a hard time.

For example, this is the function for saving the diagram

```
$(function save() {
        //$("#editor").resizable("destroy");
        Objs = [];
        $('#editor').each(function(){
            Objs.push({id:$(this).attr('id'), html:$(this).html(), left:$(this).css('left'), top:$(this).css('top'), width:$(this).css('width'), height:$(this).css('height')});
        });
        console.log(Objs);

    });
```

Also, I've been trying the stringify for getting the data and parse for loading but I still can't figure it out.

Is there a way that I can save jsplumb to json or xml?

Comment: In your scenario, does each connection have individual endpoints or is it possible for single endpoint to have multiple connections?

Comment: In my scenario, it is possible for single endpoint to have multiple connections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a connection is established, "[**connection**](http://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/events.html#evt-connection)" event is triggered. You need to store the connection endpoints details in that triggered function so that you can retrieve them later.

First make sure that you have set proper id for your endpoints. You can manually set at time of endpoint creation as:

```
var e0 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("div1",{uuid:"div1_ep1"}),  // You can also set uuid based on element it is placed on
 e1 = jsPlumb.addEndpoint("div2",{uuid:"div2_ep1"});
```

Now bind the **connection** event where you will store the established connections info:

```
var uuid, index=0; // Array to store the endpoint sets.
jsPlumb.bind("connection", function(ci) {
    var eps = ci.connection.endpoints;
    console.log(eps[0].getUuid() +"->"+ eps[1].getUuid()); // store this information in 2d-Array or any other format you wish
    uuid[index][0]=eps[0].getUuid(); // source endpoint id
    uuid[index++][1]=eps[1].getUuid(); // target endpoint id
    }
});
```

You can convert the array information to JSON format and store it. On restoring, connect the endpoints based on uuid. code:

```
jsPlumb.connect({ uuids:["div1_ep1","div2_ep1"] });
```

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajnWU/10/) for making connections based on endpoints.

**NOTE:** The above code is only for restoring the connection and endpoints information after you have restored the div's css. You can store the css properties of all div's by using the same method which you wrote in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently tied this and its working

```
function createJSON(){
        var data = new Object();
        $("input[class = process]").each(function(){
            data[$(this).attr("name")] = $(this).val();

        jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);


    });

        console.log(jsonString);

    }
```